# Sum over subsets of a function of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binomial-coefficients

Let: $$I=\{1,\dots,n\}.$$

What is the value of: $$\sum_{J\subseteq I} {\binom{g+2|J|-1}{2|J|-1}}$$

where $g$ is a positive integer and $|J|$ represents the number of elements of $J$.

---

Possible first step:

The given expression equals: $$\sum_{d=0}^n {\binom{n}{d} \binom{g+2d-1}{2d-1}}$$

Comment: May be related: [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).

Comment: I've rewritten the problem in a form that looks more like Vandermonde's identity, but it's still not obvious how to apply it. The $2$ is particularly problematic.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha extracts a factor of $(g+1)n$ and gives up. That implies that there is no closed form solution. Do you have any grounds for expecting there to be one?

Comment: Just hope I guess!